# Is there a way to set the firstRender-Variable of the OnAfterRender method in bunit testing?

Tags: c#, xunit, bunit

Imagine I have the following class and I want to test both, the `firstRender = false` and the `firstRender=true` "path". For this sake I am using bunit and xunit.

```
public class ToTest {
    protected async override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
         if(firstRender)
         {
              //do stuff
         }
         else
         {
              //do other stuff
         }
    }
}
```

```
public class TestClass : TestContext
{
    
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        //Arrange stuff before this method
        var cut = RenderComponent<News>(parameters => parameters
        .Add(p => p.authenticationStateTask, stateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()));
    }

}
```

Is there a way to set the firstRender-Variable of the OnAfterRender method in bunit testing?
Do I have to adjust the RenderComponent-Parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bUnit allows you to perform multiple renders of a component under test. The first render will always have `firstRender` set to `true`, and any additional renders will have it set to `false`, just like the regular Blazor runtime.

For example:

```cs
public class TestClass : TestContext
{
    
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        // First render, where firstRender is true
        var cut = RenderComponent<News>(parameters => parameters
           .Add(p => p.Param, "Bar"));

       // Second render, where firstRender is false
       cut.Render();

       // Third render, with new parameters set during the render life-cycle 
       // and where firstRender is also false
       cut.SetParametersAndRender(parameters => parameters
           .Add(p => p.Param, "Foo"));
    }

}
```

Learn more here: https://bunit.dev/docs/interaction/trigger-renders.html